# Can not add calendar subscriptions to iCloud

Tags: icloud, calendar

I can't add subscriptions to my iCloud Calendar anymore. If I want for example add the holiday calendar via [Mac Calendar Setting](https://p27-calendars.icloud.com/holidays/de_de.ics) I get this error message

> The server responded: “403” to operation CalDAVAddSubscriptionCalendarQueueableOperation.

I am pretty sure, this was possible! Did this change?

Comment: You mean the ics file doesn't download, or you get that error when it tries to open in Calendar?

Comment: I get an error when I add the subscription.

Comment: 403 is a pretty clear error - forbidden. The connection is being made but not allowed for some reason. Maybe check your iCloud login, from control panel & web, make sure all seems OK.

Comment: My iCloud login is fine. Everything works, except this.